# How can I add right border on an UIView on Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview, border

I have an `UIView` on the top of my screen and I want to add a right border of 1 pixel to it.

Here is the code that I have by the moment:

```
var border = CALayer()
border.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241, green: 10, blue: 9, alpha: 1).cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: topView.frame.width + 1, y: 0, width: 1, height: topView.frame.height)
topView.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

but I am not able to get it work.

What can I do to add a right border to my `UIView`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code works for me, You are setting the position of the frame outside of the bounds of the view, change it to - 1 (instead of width + 1) and then it should display as expected. (I changed the colours to make it easier to see in playground)

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let borderLayer = CALayer()
borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - 1, y: 0, width: 1, height: view.frame.height)
view.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Comment: Ok, in my real example I was using 255, 255, 255 as background for my border (white). I am feeling totally silly right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cliptobounds = false on topview or keep the line within the frame